# Facebook Insights - Post Details

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

In the "Posts" section of Facebook Insights, you can click on your latest posts and get detailed information about them:

[image: Facebook post details]

I'm trying to recreate this data in a web application, using the [Facebook SDK for .NET](http://facebooksdk.net/). I have found most of these numbers through Facebook's Graph API, e.g:

```
.../v2.3/(page-id_post-id)/insights/post_impressions_unique/lifetime
.../v2.3/(page-id_post-id)/insights/post_stories_by_action_type/lifetime
.../v2.3/(page-id_post-id)/insights/post_consumptions_by_type/lifetime
.../v2.3/(page-id_post-id)/insights/post_negative_feedback_by_type/lifetime
```

...except the **post content** and the **numbers marked in red**. Using Fiddler, it looks like Facebook fetches these values from a URL outside the Graph API:

```
https://www.facebook.com/ajax/pages/insights/view_story/...
```

However, that URL is only accessible if you're logged in to Facebook. So, the question is:

- *Given an access token, can my (server-side) web application somehow get the post content, or at least the missing numbers?* Preferably using the Facebook SDK, but any solution will do.

**Update:**

As @CBroe points out, simply querying the post id itself gives you enough info to recreate the post content:

```
.../v2.3/(post-id)?fields=name,message,picture,link
```

So, the last piece of the puzzle is to get the missing numbers. "Likes - On Post" can be found by querying the post's `/likes` with a summary:

```
.../v2.3/(page-id_post-id)/likes?limit=0&summary=true
```

..but "Comments - On Post" and "Shares - On Post" are trickier.

- Querying `.../v2.3/(page-id_post-id)/comments` does give the number of comments on the post, but doesn't include answers to those comments, which are included in the number **5** in the picture above. You can recursively query `/comments` on each comment id, but that would generate too many queries to be worth it.
- One might think that querying `.../v2.3/(post-id)/sharedposts` could give you the number of times a post has been shared, but it only gives you a few of the shared instances (due to other users' privacy settings?)

Comment: What do you mean by “post content”, the actual message and link that was shared? That is not part of insights, but of the post object itself. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/post#fields And for comments and shared posts, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/post#edges

Comment: @CBroe - Thanks, that's helpful! I have tried a few more things and added an update to the question. However, some numbers are still missing. Especially it would be great to find **"Shares - On Post"** somehow. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to clarify, you're trying to get the number of likes, comments, and shares.

- Likes `[post_id]/likes?summary=True&limit=0` 
  NOTE: You can also call it when calling the post fields `[post_id]?fields=id,likes.summary(true).limit(0)`
- Comments `[post_id]/comments?summary=true&limit=0` 
  NOTE: comments edge has a param `filter` https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/object/comments which may be why you see different numbers
  NOTE: You can also call then when calling the post fields `[post_id]?fields=id,comments.summary(true).limit(0)`
- Shares [post_id]?fields=shares 
  the sharedposts edge is empty b/c you don't have "read_stream" permission for the user's posts, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/object/sharedposts#readperms

**Edit (by OP):**

Adjustments to get the same numbers that are presented in the "Post Details" popup:

- Comments - On Post: `(page-id_post-id)/comments?filter=stream&summary=true&limit=0`

  - *Using only `post-id` without prepending `page-id` gives the same result, but you also get a debug message saying "...actual number of results returned might be different depending on privacy settings."*
- Shares - On Post: `(post-id)/sharedposts?fields=id`

  - *Don't prepend `page-id` here - that yields an empty result set.*
  - Sadly, `?summary=true` doesn't work, so I used the `fields` filter just to reduce the amount of data.
  - *The suggested `(post-id)?fields=shares` gives a different number which seems similar to the insights numbers, but doesn't add up to any of them.*

Comment: Thanks! `filter` and `read_stream` gives the result I was after. Also, the "inline" syntax including other post fields was a nice feature!